# I Want to Authenticate my userid and password comparing what i get from api request flutter

Tags: flutter, authentication, toast

I create a login page. in that page if userId and password is incorrect, then it will show toast or snackbar.
though i tried myself, but i don't know, how to check my userid and password is correct or incorrect based on api?

**here is login button **

```
child: RaisedButton(
                  child: Text('Login'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    String _email = _emailController.text.trim();
                    String _password = _passwordController.text.trim();
                    setState(() {
                      _futureAlbum = createAlbum(
                          _emailController.text, 
                          _passwordController.text);
                    });
                       if(){
                       // in this section i want to check email id and password comparing from api request
                           }

                  },
                  color: Colors.green,
                  textColor: Colors.white,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 10),
                ),
```

**Here is Api Request**

```
Future<Album> createAlbum(String employee_custom_id, String password) async {
    final response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse('https://portal-api.jomakhata.com/api/auth/login'),
      headers: <String, String>{
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: jsonEncode(<String, String>{
        'employee_custom_id': employee_custom_id,
        'password': password,
      }),
    );
    final data = json.decode(response.body);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      saveToken(data);
      Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => Main()),
          (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
      log('$data');
      return Album.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to create album.');
    }
  }
```

**this is api response**

```
{token: eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjI5MDAsImlzcyI6Imh0dHBzOi8vcG9ydGFsLWFwaS5qb21ha2hhdGEuY29tL2FwaS9hdXRoL2xvZ2luIiwiaWF0IjoxNjMwNjk4MTY3LCJ..., message: success, userId: 2900, passwordChanged: yes}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you're building the API yourself or have a say in how it is built. That said, please do not perform password checks on the frontend or return a user's password via an API. Doing so will expose your app to security attacks. Here's why:

1. A user can circumvent this process and call the API directly
2. You are potentially exposing the user's actual password by fetching it from the API

This logic is usually handled at the backend where the API sends you a response based on whether the details entered are correct or not. Please let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: Thanks. but when i hit on backend using api. i get token and some data like success msg. so, its mandatory to set toast in login page. please tell me how to set toast by checking backend? if userId or password is incorrect then user can't go to main page.

Comment: If you are getting a success message and token from the API, then it means the login was successful. You can set a toast using the [fluttertoast](https://pub.dev/packages/fluttertoast)  package. This would typically be an if or switch statement based on the API's response. Please refer to your API documentation to know how the response messages are structured.

Comment: {token: eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjI5MDAsImlzcyI6Imh0dHBzOi8vcG9ydGFsLWFwaS5qb21ha2hhdGEuY29tL2FwaS9hdXRoL2xvZ2luIiwiaWF0IjoxNjMwNjk4MTY3LCJ..., message: success, userId: 2900, passwordChanged: yes}

Answer (score 1):

You can check if your userId and password are correct based on the API response.

If the userId and password are correct you should get a status code of `200` as usual.
However, if the userId or password is incorrect you should get a `403` status code.

From the above, anytime the status code is **not** `200` it means the userId or password is incorrect, you can then display the toast.

Comment: can you implement this for me?